# What is the mediawiki install path on Ubuntu when you install it from the Repos?

Tags: mediawiki

What is the mediawiki install path on Ubuntu when you install it from the Repos?

Specifically looking for the extensions folder.

Answer (score 2):

`/var/lib/mediawiki/extensions/`